# how many rows does interpolation consider?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, interpolation, data-cleaning

How does pandas' DataFrame.interpolation() work in relation to the amount of rows it considers:

1. is it just the row before the NaNs and the row right after?
2. Or is it the whole DataFrame (how does that work at 1 million rows?)
3. Or another way (please explain)

Edit:
(with method=='polynomial' ideally)

Answer (score 0):

With `method='polynomial'`, `DataFrame.interpolate()` starts with the first non-NaN values, and stops at the last non-NaN value, leaving leading and trailing NaNs unchanged:

```
>>> n = np.nan
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([n,n,4,2,4,n,n,2,n,n,n,n,n,])
>>> df
      0
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   4.0
3   2.0
4   4.0
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   2.0
8   NaN
9   NaN
10  NaN
11  NaN
12  NaN

>>> df.interpolate(method='polynomial', order=2)
           0
0        NaN  <--- 
1        NaN  <--- first 2 NaN values are unchanged
2   4.000000
3   2.000000
4   4.000000
5   5.076923
6   4.410256
7   2.000000  <--- last non-NaN value
8        NaN  <--- this and subsequent NaN values unchanged
9        NaN
10       NaN
11       NaN
12       NaN
```

If you'd like the leading and trailing NaN values filled, just use `bfill` and `ffill`:

```
>>> df.interpolate(method='polynomial', order=2).bfill().ffill()
           0
0   4.000000
1   4.000000
2   4.000000
3   2.000000
4   4.000000
5   5.076923
6   4.410256
7   2.000000
8   2.000000
9   2.000000
10  2.000000
11  2.000000
12  2.000000
```

Comment: "and after interpolating" ... no i meant during the interpolation itself.

With how many non-NaN values from the start, does it interpolate? (maximum).

In your example: 
(with method=='polynomial' ideally)
Does it only use the ilocs 2,3,4 or only the 4?

Comment: @benjamin_z check now.  :)

Comment: maybe we're talking about something different. I just want to understand why exactly the ilo 5,6 change if you add more (valid) values (non-NaN) before it.

And why it stops being influenced after having added 30 values before (and changing the first of those to a giant number, to check if it would still influence iloc 5,6).

So my thesis is that under polynomial it only goes back a certain amount of rows for each NaN...  but how many, and how to find out?